# Smooth camera rotation on mouse down in THREE.js scene

Tags: three.js

I am trying to achieve smooth camera rotation effects similar to this http://showroom.littleworkshop.fr/

But the camera rotates in all three axis (Yaw, Pitch and Roll).

My code is:

```
var targetQuat = new THREE.Quaternion();

OnMouseDownHandler() {

    var mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3(VS.Mouse.x, VS.Mouse.y);
    mouseVector.unproject(VS.Camera);
    var dir = mouseVector.sub(VS.Camera.position).normalize();
    var oldPos = VS.Camera.position.clone();
    var cameraPosN = oldPos.normalize();

    var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(dir.x, dir.y, dir.z);
    var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ), Math.PI / 4 );
    v1.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

    targetQuat.setFromUnitVectors(cameraPosN, v1);
}

///////////
renderLoop() {

    requestAnimationFrame(VS.RenderFrame);

    var deltaTime = VS.Clock.getDelta();

    VS.Camera.quaternion.slerp(targetQuat, deltaTime);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please share your current progress in a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/. This will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Have you looked into how [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=panorama#webgl_panorama_cube) handles its camera?

Comment: @TheJim01 this uses Orbit camera controls. My uses case needs a FirstPersonCamera control. I have tried using the one provided with THREE.js but needs a lot of changes.